# Error: exceeds maximum length limit of 255 characters while inserting data from Oracle to Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(Submitting on behalf of a Snowflake User)

---

I'm facing below error while inserting data from oracle to snowflake. Does anyone know why the error is?.

```
Note: Error column defined "VARCHAR" datatype
```

I understand that where an explicit length is specified as VARCHAR(255), an error may be encountered because (as per Snowflake documentation): "If a length is not specified, the default is the maximum length."

Single-byte:  16,777,216

Multi-byte:  Between 8,388,608 (2 bytes per character) and 4,194,304 (4 bytes per character)

I've heard that in Oracle, I could change the data type and length to VARCHAR2(4000) or in Snowflake to default VARCHAR without specifying the length.

I have table in snowflake as like below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test1
(
test1 varchar
)


INSERT INTO test1 values(<values from oracle cursor>)
```

While executing INSERT query stuck up with error - `Error: exceeds maximum length limit of 255 characters`

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answer posited by the User)

> Its due to the escape character in the string, Thanks all for your
>   valuable input.

---

HOWEVER - Are there any additional recommendations or more efficient ways to address the questions posed by the User? Thanks!